# How to disable error message-dialog in apache.batik.swing when displaing a SVG file?

Tags: svg, apache

I get an error message box when displaying a SVG file with apache batik swing. Is it possible to turn it off or even better, get it to accept SVG-parameters?

[image]

The simple code is:

```
import org.apache.batik.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SVGViewer {

  JSVGCanvas svgCanvas = new JSVGCanvas();

  public SVGViewer(JFrame frame, String filename) {
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add("Center", svgCanvas);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    svgCanvas.setURI("file:/" + filename);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            frame.dispose();
          }          
    });
    
  }
}
```